# BCS: Edit button in context menu works, but edit button in display form is disabled

Tags: bcs, bdc-model, bdc

I created an external content type für a MS SQL Server view. I created a list from it and three different views and I changed the form with InfoPath. All of this done without VS, only SharePoint Designer.

The data is displayed correctly and when I click on the dropdown menu of an item and **choose "Edit Item", I can change and save it**.

[image: context menu shows both entries enabled]

[image: save button enabled and works]

But when I open the display form of the item by clicking on the link or clicking on "View Item" in the context menu, **the display form does not enable the "Edit Item" button** in its ribbon.

[image: edit item button not enabled ... why?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" this now with a workaround:

When you change the item form via InfoPath, SharePoint Designer creates two new ASPX forms "displayifs.aspx" and "editifs.aspx" and sets them default. I needed only the edit form to be customized.

**So I solved this by setting the old "DispForm.aspx" as the default form for viewing (again).** Instantly the Edit Item button worked again.